# combine nested modules with require.js optimizer

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js

I have the following.

```
require([ 'a', 'b' ], function() {     
   if(x){
       require([ 'c', 'd' ], function( ) {});
   }   
});
```

`c` will always be loaded with `d`. Is there anyway to make the optimizer optimize `c` and `d` so that they will load as one file?

EDIT:

Also im using r.js as the optimizer. And the modules for my build script look something like this.

```
modules: [
    {
        name: "main",
    },
    {
        name: "c",
            include: ["d"]
    }
]
```

This will include `d` in `c`, but both `c` and `d` are still loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/n33UK52SZnY/YIWolEsJbr0J)

You can set up a path mapping in production to inform RequireJS that `d` is located at `c`.

Simply do:

```
paths: {
  'd': 'c'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`r.js` (I'm assuming that's what you mean by "optimizer") won't touch `c` and `d` unless you explicitly ask it to [*"You can always explicitly add modules that are not found via the optimizer's static analysis by using the **include** option."* - from [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization)]. If you do that they'll end up in the optimized output and will be loaded at runtime together with `a` and `b` and the rest of the code (even if `x` is `false` and the `require` block is never reached).

If you don't, `r.js` will skip that block and `RequireJS` will only resolve `c` and `d` at runtime (if `x` is `true`), when it's too late to do any optimizations or concatenations.

**RE: the edit**

The correct way to force including `c` and `d` in `main` would be:

```
    modules: [ {
        name: "main",
        include: ["c", "d"]
    } ]
```

This means: *"include everything `main.js` requires explicitly but also add `c.js` and `d.js`"*

**RE: the comment:**

Oh, you're right, your configuration will also create an optimised `c.js` that includes both `c` and `d` but `RequireJS` will load the 'standalone' `d` anyway. Strangely, it will still use the `d` from the optimised file and won't even evaluate the standalone `d.js` (checked by editing contents of optimised `c.js` and `d.js`). I guess RequireJS requests all listed dependencies immediately since it has no way of knowing that loading `c` will satifsy the `d` dependency (this is only known after the module is loaded and processed). That makes sense because the only other option would be request the files sequentially, one by one - that would be a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes I'm using r.js and I have tried using the include option. This didn't work for me.

Comment: about the edit: wouldn't that just produce one file with `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` in it? I want `c` and `d` to load as one file and only if they are needed.